# What's the idiom for "sizeof type T on my CUDA device(s)"?

Tags: cuda, portability, idioms

The sizes of types on CUDA devices can theoretically differ from their sizes on the host platform. So, what's the idiomatic way of expressing "sizeof(T) on my CUDA device", in code - other than rolling your own map of type id's to values you know?

Comment: The CUDA runtime has been specifically designed so that host and device types match in size. So no, they can't theoretically differ in size. The only corner cases are structure alignment, and even those are consistent.

Comment: @talonmies, do you confirm cuda changed the size of bool ? if yes, do you remember when ? which version ? For the rest, I totally agree, and a basic sizeof(T) check should suit most needs.

Comment: @talonmies: But what about [LP64 vs LLP64 compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) ?

Comment: @einpoklum: That is irrelevant. The whole reason the CUDA toolchain is so deeply integrated with the host compiler and libc implementation is so that it doesn't matter. Whatever platform you are on, sizeof fundamental types is consistent in host and device code. It might be different *between platforms*, but on a given platform it always matches. You build on the platform you run on, and `sizeof` emits the correct value at compile time.

Comment: @talonmies: So, what you're saying is that if my host's `int` is 64-bit, so will my device int? But that doesn't seem to make sense, because a lot of wrappers for device code take `int`s and in actuality it has to be 32-bit values (e.g. shuffles).

Comment: There is no supported CUDA platform where `sizeof(int)` is 64, so again, that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @talonmies: (sigh) ok... make that an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing you have asked about is required on any currently supported CUDA platform. One of the reasons the CUDA toolchain is so heavily integrated with the host compiler and host C++ runtime library is so that it is *guaranteed* that the size of fundamental types on the host and device always match. No idiomatic translation of sizes is required. The result of `sizeof` will always be the same for both host and device. Note that the size of fundamental types can differ from platform to platform (Windows is a LLP64/IL32P64 platform, linux and OS X are LP64/I32LP64 platforms), but that has no effect on the GPU.

Note also that the GPU can impose alignment requirements on composite types which might mean that the compiled sizes are different from what you might expect. The conditions under which this applies is discussed in detail in the documentation.

For example, consider the following trivial example code:

```
#include <cstdio>

__device__ __host__ __noinline__ void printsizes(const char* title)
{
    printf("%s\n", title);
    printf("sizeof(void*) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(void*));
    printf("sizeof(char) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof(bool) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(bool));
    printf("sizeof(short) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(short));
    printf("sizeof(int) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(long) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(long));
    printf("sizeof(long long) = %ld\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(long long));
}

__global__ void printkernel()
{
    printsizes("On the device:");
}

int main()
{
    printsizes("On the host:");

    printkernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and run on a Linux 64 platform yields this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -m64 -o sizeof64 sizeof.cu
$ ./sizeof64
On the host:
sizeof(void*) = 8
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 8
sizeof(long long) = 8
On the device:
sizeof(void*) = 8
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 8
sizeof(long long) = 8
```

Built on a 64 bit Windows platform it yields this:

```
>nvcc -arch=sm_21 -m64 sizes.cu
sizes.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp
>a.exe
On the host:
sizeof(void*) = 8
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 4
sizeof(long long) = 8
On the device:
sizeof(void*) = 8
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 4
sizeof(long long) = 8
```

Built on a 32 bit Windows platform it yields this:

```
>nvcc -arch=sm_21 -m32 sizes.cu
sizes.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

C:\Users\david\Documents>a.exe
On the host:
sizeof(void*) = 4
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 4
sizeof(long long) = 8
On the device:
sizeof(void*) = 4
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(bool) = 1
sizeof(short) = 2
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(long) = 4
sizeof(long long) = 8
```

Note that the sizes of `void *` and `long`can vary between platforms. But in every case the GPU sizes match the host sizes. This is a basic design tenet of the CUDA driver and GPU runtime.